# For loop on unique ID

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

Sheet1 is a continuous list of everything being recorded and kept.
Sheet2 is an updated list that is retrieved, with updated lines and new lines. Within the lists in column A is a unique ID for every entry in numeric value.

I am trying to go through every unique ID in sheet2, look for a match in sheet1

- if there is a match, replace that entire row values with the new values from sheet2
- if there is no match it needs to be placed in the last blank row (+1 from xlUp).

I have tried other ways that are not below like using scripting.dictionary.

The way I am trying to do this results in every cell that the “for” is looking at to be true for the if not equal. Every item is posted multiple times below xlUp.

```vb
Sub test()

Dim enter As Worksheet
Dim take As Worksheet
Set enter = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set take = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim a1 As Long
Dim b1 As Long
Dim c1 As Long

a1 = take.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
b1 = enter.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
c1 = enter.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = 1 To a1 'this statement works fine to find the matching value to replace.
    For K = 1 To b1
        If take.Cells(i, 1) = enter.Rows(K, 1) Then
            enter.Rows(i).EntireRow = take.Rows(K).EntireRow.Value
        End If
    Next
Next

'below is other things i have tried

'For I = 1 To a1
'    For J = 1 To b1
'        If enter.Cells(J, 1) <> take.Cells(I, 1) Then
'            enter.Rows(c1).EntireRow = take.Rows(I).EntireRow.Value
'            c1 = c1 + 1
'        End If
'    Next
'Next

'For i = 1 To a1
'    For j = 1 To b1
'        If take.Cells(i, 1) = enter.Cells(j, 1) Then
'            enter.Rows(j).EntireRow = take.Rows(i).EntireRow.Value
'            GoTo Skip
'        ElseIf j = b1 Then
'            enter.Rows(c1).EntireRow = take.Rows(i).EntireRow.Value
'            c1 = c1 + 1
'        End If
'    Next
'Skip:
'Next
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Are both lists unique i.e. are there no duplicates?

Comment: And how large is the data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hy

```
Public Sub MyCopy()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ws1")
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ws2")
    
    Dim col As String
    col = "A"
    
    Dim i As Long, targetRow As Long, q As Long
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    With wsSource
        For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
            
            Set sourceRange = .Range(col & i)
            targetRow = GetDataRow(wsTarget, col, sourceRange.value)
        
        
            For q = 0 To 30
        
                wsTarget.Range(col & targetRow).Offset(0, q).value = sourceRange.Offset(0, q).value
            
            
            Next q
            
            
        Next i
    End With

End Sub











Private Function GetDataRow(ws As Worksheet, col As String, value As String) As Long
    With ws
        Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
            
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If .Range(col & i).value = value Then
                GetDataRow = i
                GoTo exitFunc
            End If
        Next i
        
        GetDataRow = lastRow + 1
    End With
exitFunc:
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and I apologize about the late reply. Your solution works perfectly for my case. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

### Update Worksheet (`For Each ... Next`, `Application.Match`)

[image]

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateWorksheet()

    Const sName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const sFirst As String = "A1"
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirst As String = "A1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim slCell As Range
    Set slCell = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, sws.Range(sFirst).Column).End(xlUp)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(sFirst, slCell)
   
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dlCell As Range:
    Set dlCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dws.Range(dFirst).Column).End(xlUp)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(dFirst, dlCell)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim cIndex As Variant
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        cIndex = Application.Match(sCell.Value, drg, 0)
        If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
            drg.Cells(cIndex).EntireRow.Value = sCell.EntireRow.Value
        Else
            Set dlCell = dlCell.Offset(1)
            dlCell.EntireRow.Value = sCell.EntireRow.Value
        End If
    Next sCell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and I apologize about the late reply. Your code works perfectly except for one condition. That condition would be if there was two entries on sheet2 with the same unique ID. The first being the new ID and the second being an update to that ID. When running your code it drags two new entries to sheets1 instead of taking the first new ID and updating it with a second one later down the row to sheet1. Toth's solution worked with that condition but if you like the challenge I would be interested in seeing you when you come up with.

Comment: Just add `Set drg = dws.Range(dFirst, dlCell)` to the bottom of the `Else` statement (right above `End If`).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!