# When a match is found, copy row from one sheet to the row where the match was found in macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table on the MainDashboard that is updated by a macro. It copies data from selected sheets and updates this main table. Here is my code but I am stuck. I need it to:

Loop through every sheet in Sheet List

Loop through every value in the first column of the tables on each sheet

Check to see if these IDs are in the first column of the Main Dashboard table

If yes, Copy everything on that row and paste it over the same row where the value was found on the main Dashboard table

If no, add it to the bottom of the row

When finished have a MsgBox that says, you have modified x entries and added x new entries

```
Sub Update()

    Dim SheetList As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim TaskListTable As Range
    Dim TaskList As ListObject
    Dim SortColumn As Range
    Dim TaskId As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Range
    Dim MDLastRow As Range
    
    'What I want the Excel program to do before I start
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .StatusBar = "Running..."
    End With
    
    'List Sheet Names into an Array Variable
    SheetList = Array(S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9, S10, S11, S12, S13, S14)
    
    'Loop through list
    For x = LBound(SheetList) To UBound(SheetList)
        'Code will fail unless you activate the sheet first
        SheetList(x).Activate
        
        'Loop for b15 in column 1 down for every row to last row
        LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        MDLastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For Each TaskID In Range("B15": LastRow)
            If WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("B15:MDLastRow"),  Then
            SheetList(x).Range("TaskID").End(xlRight).Copy
            
            'PASTE TO ENTIRE ROW WHERE THE MATCH WAS FOUND
            End If
            
            'Else add row to the bottom
            SheetList(x).Range("TaskID").End(xlRight).Copy
            MainDashboard.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Next x
    
    MainDashboard.Activate
    
    'MsgBox
    'You have Modified X tasks
    'You have Added X tasks
    
    'Sort the table by the latest Date
    Set TaskList = MainDashboard.ListObjects("Task_List")
    Set SortColumn = Range("Task_List[DATE]")
    With TaskList.Sort
       .SortFields.Clear
       .SortFields.Add Key:=SortColumn, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
       .Header = xlYes
       .Apply
    End With
    
    'What I want the Excel program to do after I have finished
   With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .StatusBar = "Complete"
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67815098/vba-for-loop-on-unique-id/67815789#67815789) is a solution that I did earlier today. It is for one worksheet though. It is easily tested. Let me know if that's about what you need so I could rewrite it for more worksheets. In the solution, `Sheet1` is the main (destination) worksheet.

Comment: Always helps to explain what the *specific* issue is that you're facing.  Listing what you want to happen and including code without explaining where/how the code falls short just makes more work for us...

Comment: @vbasic2008 thanks a lot! managed to do everything I wanted to.